# Having Slick use the entities defined in my tables to fill my SQL queries responses

Tags: scala, slick

Assuming I have a `Person` case class and a `PersonTable` defined in Slick, I was wondering if it's possible to have something like this compiling and working:

```
case class Person(id: Long, ....)

class PersonTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "PERSON") {
  def serverId = column[Long]("ID")
  ...

  def * = (id, ...).mapTo[Person]
}

sql"select person.* from PERSON JOIN USER ON USER.ID = PERSON.ID".as[List[Person]]
```

I could see that

```
sql"select person.* from PERSON JOIN USER ON USER.ID = PERSON.ID".as[(a,b,c,...,z)]
```

seems to at least compile, but I'd like to have this working with my already defined entities instead, and to work with lists.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you to use Slick query DSL instead of using `sql` string interpolation - this will provide you possibility to map result to your case classes out of the box.

Comment: The query SQL is fine if all you want to do are simple one, maybe two, table queries. Any more than that, and it slowly starts degenerating into a complete mess, until all you have is a big ball of mud that no one is happy with. That's what happened to us with squeryl. On the other hand, systems that happened to be developed with simple string based SQL queries have been by far the easier to maintain, extend and debug, so I'd like to develop this thing that way.

Answer (score 1):

For most queries the Slick query DSL is way nicer/easier, definitely do that first! But for complex queries I agree that sometimes good old sql works well. Sometimes it gets really complex to figure out the DSL or (worse) in some cases it produces very inefficient SQL. (though it has gotten better)

AFAIK you still need the somewhat annoying `GetResult` mapping from result tuples to case classes for the `.as[]` to work. If you don't add a `.headOption` it produces a list.

Something like this:

```
implicit val getPersonResult = GetResult(r => Target(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, ... ))

db.run(sql"select person.* from PERSON JOIN USER ON USER.ID = PERSON.ID".as[Person])
   .map(_.toList)
```

Hope this helps.